# Is it possible to profile my code using CoffeeScript for Node.js?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, v8

I know I can profile with `--prof` when running `node myfile.js`, but what if I run `coffee myfile.coffee`? Let's assume I can't just compile to .js, because there are A LOT of dependences in the file.

How can I run a v8 profiler?

Comment: you may also want to use [nprof](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-profiler/blob/nprof/nprof) file to turn v8.log into something readable. I was doing some profiling today and it's unreadable in raw format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you can pass the `--nodejs` command line parameter to `coffee` and anything after that will get passed directly to node. Thanks to https://twitter.com/#!/oluwie who doesn't want to take credit but told me the answer

Answer (score 9):

Try `--nodejs PARAM`. See `coffee --help`.